# Cleanup of leftover/invalid translation jobs

Tags: 2013-sp1, translation-manager

Recently we have switched TMS servers and I'm wondering what is the proper way to handle jobs that were in progress in the mean time. I was told that the jobs inside the TMS were migrated, however in Tridion I still have the old jobs which were created referencing the old TMS. I'm thinking along the lines of deleting and recreating the jobs (along with deleting from TMS), however I'm facing some difficulties:

Only one of these jobs is in `Error Retrieving` and that single one can be deleted, but all the other ones are `In Translation` for which the `Delete` button is disabled. See below:

[image]

Is there a civilised manner to resolve this issue, or should I just delete them from the Translation database?

Thank you.

PS. Just to provide all the information, I'm including the errors/exceptions... when trying to open these jobs, the following error is shown (but this is expected):

```
Invalid External Client ID passed in CTA Request.
```

Also the Translationmanger log is filled with errors:

```
Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Polling interval increased to 00:15:00 due to errors in the previous operations.
Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Invalid External Client ID passed in CTA Request.
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TmsConfiguration.CheckCtaResponse(Response response, String clientId)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TmsConfiguration.GetConfigurationResponse()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TmsConfiguration..ctor(String id, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TranslationSystemConfiguration.GetTranslationSystemConfiguration(String id, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.RetrieveFromTranslationTask.Process()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.ServiceTask.ThreadMethod()

Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Polling interval increased to 00:15:00 due to errors in the previous operations.
w3wp    392 Invalid External Client ID passed in CTA Request.
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TmsConfiguration.CheckCtaResponse(Response response, String clientId)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TmsConfiguration.GetConfigurationResponse()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TmsConfiguration..ctor(String id, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.TranslationSystemConfiguration.GetTranslationSystemConfiguration(String id, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.WorkflowStatus.<GetLanguages>b__33(TmsTranslationJob tmsJob)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__31`3.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.WorkflowStatus.GetLanguages(TranslationJob job, IEnumerable`1 workflowStatusData)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.WorkflowStatus..ctor(TranslationJob job, IEnumerable`1 workflowStatusData, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationJob.get_WorkflowStatus()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Model.Services.DTO.TranslationJobDTO..ctor(TranslationJob job, UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Model.Services.TranslationJobManagerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Load>b__5(UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Model.Services.TransactionAndUserContextAwareImpl.ExecuteInUserContext[T](Boolean requiresTransaction, Func`2 code)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.UI.Model.Services.TranslationJobManager.Load(String jobId)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation jobs eventually ended up in an error state and were removed from the CME using the built in `Delete` button.

Comment: In your question, you mentioned that some of the jobs were in "In Translation" state. I am just wondering whether you have made any changes to move it to "Error retrieving" state?

Comment: None at all, and because this was a lower priority issue, I haven't been monitoring it for some time. There was an outage of connectivity between the CM and TMS at one point however.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is very bad idea to switch TMS server while you have live jobs.

If you did no changed TMS yet then ask TMS admins to cancel all active jobs that you have for this CM. And let them become canceled in TM.

If you already switched then there is no supported way of removing jobs. You have to contact customer support so they can help you with this.

Comment: Yeah, obviously it's a bad idea, however we had no choice (we were cut off from the server without any advance notice). 
The switch already has been made.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this involves 3 steps

1. Notedown the component id and delete that from the database table directly.

Steps : Open `App_data` table and search for the Component ID in the `subject_reference_id` column, delete the matching one

2. Upon database record deletion, refreshing the CME Translations UI, we can see the translation job state as "Error Retrieving" instead of "In Progress" state
3. Now, we can delete the Translation Job. Also, delete any active processes in the CME, (under Administration -> Workflow management -> active processes)

Comment: What a nonsense.
All wrong